# Error using newcommand "\begin{document} ended by end{center}"

Tags: errors

I've noticed that I'm using a particular code snippet for including and centering a figure with its caption all over the place in my Masters thesis.

I decided that for cleanliness and flexibility, I should extract it into a `\newcommand`.

```
% This command creates a centered figure. 
% The first argument is for the filepath, the second for the label, 
% and the third is for the caption.
\newcommand{\cfigure}[3]{
    \begin{center}
    \end{center}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{#1}
      \caption{#3}
       \label{#2}
    \end{figure}
    \end{center}
}
```

The `\newcommand` statement compiles without error, but when I actually try to use it like so:

```
\cfigure{images/Redpin_10_point2_with_labels.png}{redpin_heuristic}{Graph depicting Redpin heuristic function over a realistic domain.}
```

I get hit with the following error:

```
"\begin{document} ended by \end{center}"
```

I'm not using it in any particular environment, just the document itself.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: You have an `\end{center}` just before the final curly brace which does not have a matching (beginning) `\begin{center}`. So, this is being taken as finishing the `\begin{document}` command. Perhaps you want to get rid of `\end{center}` in the third line of your `\newcommand` definition.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least one `\end{center}` too much:

```
\newcommand{\cfigure}[3]{
    \begin{center}
   % \end{center} % here - PS
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{#1}
      \caption{#3}
       \label{#2}
    \end{figure}
    \end{center}
}
```

In fact, both `center` and `\centering` seems to be also too much.